# Make a specific Widget Scrollable

Tags: flutter, scrollable

I have 3 section in my page [Blue green and red Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeydQ.png)

what i want is how to make the red section scrollable meanwhile the other section will stuck in place

Here is my Widget Tree

```
Container(
  child: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    children: [
      Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: size.height * .12,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: kPrimaryColor),
          ),
          Container(
            height: size.height * .12,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
          ),
          // I want this part to be scrollable
          Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: size.height * 2,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      Positioned(
          top: size.height * .12 - 45,
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(360),
            child: Container(
              height: 90,
              width: 90,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.green),
              child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(360),
                  child: Image.network(defualtImage, fit: BoxFit.cover)),
            ),
          )),
    ],
  ),
);
```

I have tried wrapping my red `Column` widget with `SingeChildScrollView` and `NestedScrollView` but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your 3rd `Column` widget that you want scrollable with `SingleChildScrollView` + `Expanded` widget.

```
Expanded(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Your 3rd column widget with Red background container),
),
```

Comment: Wow it was that easy, thanks i still don't understand how these widget behave in flutter.

Comment: Basically you are having one Column, and inside that 3 Other widgets.
Expanded tells to take max height (in case of Column widget), and SingleChildScrollView makes it scrollable!

Comment: but how about wrapping the Column widget with a Container and setting it's height to double.infinity will that work too?

Comment: It won't work because Column can't have infinite viewport.. So you can't specify infinite height for the column.